# Java POM plugin issue (Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, pom.xml

When I run **mvn package exec:java** I am getting the error. Probably I have a problem with exec-maven-plugin plugin configuration. I am trying to run this demo on the Google cloud platform app engine but deploy always failed. But if I compile it on locale by **mvm package** its works fine and also I can run the application on locale without any problems.

**POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>2.3.1</micronaut.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <exec.mainClass>com.primari.backend.Application</exec.mainClass>
        <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
        <log4j.version>2.9.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xmlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlflow</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectId>primari</projectId>
                    <version>2</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-noverify</argument>
                        <argument>-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argument>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</argument>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath/>
                        <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-parameters</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>1.18.16</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.1</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                                <version>2.3.1</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>test-compile</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <compilerArgs>
                                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                                </compilerArgs>
                                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                    <path>
                                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                        <version>1.18.16</version>
                                    </path>
                                    <path>
                                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                                    </path>
                                    <path>
                                        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                                    </path>
                                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>

</project>
```

**error:**

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.012 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-07T12:23:25+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project demo: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java for parameter arguments: Cannot store value into array: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.lang.String -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginConfigurationException
```

Can you please help me where can by a problem or what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove empty `<classpath/>` It's not allowed be there in `exec:java` goal only String values accepted, see doc [exec plugin doc](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#arguments)

Another thing is micronaut overrides maven exec plugin argument section see in the project's effective pom, so the possible solution is:

```
    <arguments combine.self="override">
         <argument>-noverify</argument>
         <argument>-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argument>
         <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</argument>
         <argument>-classpath</argument>    
         <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
     </arguments>
```

Comment: I remove it but it still gives the same error. Here is my repo: https://github.com/konigt6905/primari-backend-html

Comment: Great you right now it's working in the locale, but I still can't deploy it on app engine ... I have to have some more issue in the pom.

Comment: I also checked something, see in the answer

Comment: Unfortunately, deploy on the app engine still don't work

Comment: Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:deploy (default-cli) on project demo: App Engine application deployment failed: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.cloudsdk.process.ProcessHandlerException: com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.AppEngineException: Non zero exit: 1

Comment: i think combine.self will resolve your issue

Answer (score -1):

He may have the same problem as you. [Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project](https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_36979214/article/details/107282951)
I don't understand, but try

```
<build>
 <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.0</version>
         <executions>
             <execution>
                 <goals>
                     <goal>java</goal>
                 </goals>
             </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
             <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```